# How to change shape from circle to square in this PYTHON file

Tags: python

Any Idea how to change the shape in this python file? I need it from circle to square

```
from turtle import *
from freegames import line

turns = {'red': 'yellow', 'yellow': 'red'}
state = {'player': 'yellow', 'rows': [0] * 8}

def grid():
    "Draw Connect Four grid."
    bgcolor('light blue')

    for x in range(-150, 200, 50):
        line(x, -200, x, 200)

    for x in range(-175, 200, 50):
        for y in range(-175, 200, 50):
            up()
            goto(x, y)
            dot(40, 'white')

    update()

def tap(x, y):
    "Draw red or yellow circle in tapped row."
    player = state['player']
    rows = state['rows']

    row = int((x + 200) // 50)
    count = rows[row]

    x = ((x + 200) // 50) * 50 - 200 + 25
    y = count * 50 - 200 + 25

    up()
    goto(x, y)
    dot(40, player)
    update()

    rows[row] = count + 1
    state['player'] = turns[player]

setup(420, 420, 370, 0)
hideturtle()
tracer(False)
grid()
onscreenclick(tap)
done()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your circle is being drawn with the [dot](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.dot) function from the Turtle library. The easiest way to replace it with a square is, funnily, the [circle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle) function. If you set the steps parameter to 4, it will draw the "circle" in four segments. The only other thing you would have to account for is that the "circle" starts on its rightmost side, so you will have to adjust your positioning by a value of radius over and down. Also, you're now stating radius rather than diameter, so values get halved.

So this:

```
goto(x, y)
dot(40, player)
```

will change to this:

```
goto(x+20, y)
dot(20, player)
```

You will make a similar change in your grid, assuming you want those dots to also be squares.

Comment: It doesnt work, it makes some dots out of the place where they are supposed to be

Comment: Ah, which ones are out of place? Or are they all out of place?

Comment: They are all out of place, every time i click it goes out

Comment: Hmm... I don't have access to my interpreter at the moment, and I haven't found an online interpreter to run the code. Maybe I misunderstand how the dots work. By how much are they out of place, and in which direction?

Comment: Ah! I'm guessing they're probably moved down by half the size of the token. I think I fixed that in my code.